# handling the result of multiple promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an Angular 1.X app, if I want to handle the result of two promises is there a more elegant way to achieve it than this:

```
function doSomethingWithBothResults(result1, result2) {
  return result 1 + result2;
}

$http.get('/endpoint1').then(function (result1) {

  $http.get('/endpoint2').then(function (result2) {
    doSomethingWithBothResults(result1 + result2);
  });
});
```

While this is fine when there are only 2 promises, the deep nesting that would result from a larger number is unsettling.

Comment: One option is that you could chain all your promises together. Another one will be doing the same in a recursive manner and each recursive function will receive your endpoint and nest one within the other. Another option will be to push every promise to an array and use .all on them

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for this.

It would be something like this for your snippet:

```
let promises = [];
promises.push($http.get('/endpoint1'));
promises.push($http.get('/endpoint2'));

Promise.all ( promises ).then ( function ( data ) {
    //Data from all the promises
} ).catch ( function ( error ) {
   //Error
} );
```

In the callback function `data` is an array whose each element contains the resolved value of the promise. Moreover, the order of the elements in `data` is same as in which you pushed them in the array.

This would be useful, if your promises are **independent** of each other. If they require the result of a previous promise, chaining is the way to go. Also, this will start resolving both promises at the same time, while the chaining approach will wait for one to resolve and then start resolving the next one

Comment: This will also start resolving both promises at the same time, while the other approach will wait for one to resolve and then start resolving the next one.

Comment: Could you show an example of how chaining could be used if (for example) the result of `/endpoint1` is needed to invoke `/endpoint2`

Comment: From chaining I meant, what you are doing in your question.

Comment: OK, I would call the example in my question "nesting" rather than "chaining"

Comment: @Dónal, chaining would be `prom1.then(fn).then(fn)`. Chaining doesn't really work well if you want to accumulate the promise values (IMO). Either nesting (for sequential resolution) or `Promise.all` (for parallel resolution) works better.