# loop until promise function give result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

I'm looking to loop on a promise function until I have the result I want.

As of now I'm using recursivity like this:

```
function pull() {
   dataFactory.pullFunction().then(function(res) {
      pull()       
   })
}
```

But that's giving me some front-end/style bugs for my loading bar for example.

I would do something like this:

```
function pull() {
    while (res.status == 'ONGOING') {
        dataFactory.pullFunction().then(function(res) {
            // my stuffs
        })
    }
 }
```

But when I try it the pullFunction() is never called.

Comment: `while (res.status == 'ONGOING')` - is a tight loop that if true will never allow any asynchronous code to run, and if false will never become true

Comment: Maybe you should describe in a bit more detail what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've edited my question

Comment: So as per my understanding, you want to wait till the promise is completed and so something after that. Is that it?

Comment: @PrerakSola yes I want to wait for the promise is completed and loop again until the promise result is what I'm looking for

Comment: Okay, and is your second call to the promise, dependent on the data received from the first promise?

Comment: Not really @PrerakSola

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45375623/4350275 . Can it be implemented in your scenario?

Comment: *"But that's giving me some front-end/style bugs for my loading bar for example."*: what problems? That really is the question. Please provide some code that illustrate the problem you are getting into.

Comment: It can not @PrerakSola because it isnt loop in this scenario

Comment: The bug is visual with the recursivity the loading bar is like "chopped" @trincot

Comment: I am trying my crystal ball to see why it is chopped, but maybe it is easier if you provide the code (minimal) that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use `async/await` then you have to use a function that calls itself. This is not really true recursion, because the call stack is not building up like with usual (synchronous) recursion.

But, you need to stick with promises all the way. So *return* the promise, and keep using `then`, also on the initial call of `pull` in the rest of your code.

Probably you also want to collect the data chunks you are getting from your pulls into one data set.

I will here assume that the response object will have a data attribute with the chunk of data.

Here is how that could would work (with a dummy implementation of the `pullFunction`):

```js
function pull() {
    return (function loop(data) {
        return dataFactory.pullFunction().then ( res => {
            return res.status === 'ONGOING'
                ? loop(data.concat(res.data))
                : data.concat(res.data)
        });
    })([]);
}

// Mock implementation
var dataFactory = {
    pullFunction: function () {
        console.log('pull');
        return new Promise( resolve => {
            setTimeout(_ =>
                resolve({
                    status: Math.random() > 0.7 ? 'DONE' : 'ONGOING',
                    data: [1,2,3,4]
                }),
            500)
        });
    }
}

// test it
pull().then( (data) => {
    console.log('data: ', data);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Like the way how you were able to keep the calling method concise! You mentioned 'true recursion', could u direct me to where I might be able to find learning resources for such.

Comment: I have no reference for you, but note that when `loop` is called from within the `return` expression, the previous call of `loop` already finished: only after that call finished -- some time later -- was the `then` callback called. So there is no moment that you have two unfinished call instances of `loop`. That is because the calls happen asynchronously. In true recursion, the calls happen synchronously, and so the calls of `loop` would then stack up: when the deepest call finishes, the previous one continues, ...etc. That is not happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `isOngoing` variable

```
let isOngoing = false;
function pull() {
  isOngoing = true;
  dataFactory.pullFunction()
    .then(res => {
      if(<your-condition>) {
        isOngoing = false;
      } else {
        pull();
      }
    })
}
```

**Edit**

You're dealing with asynchronous operations here, you can't loop it with the traditional `while` or `for` loop. Unless your environment allows you to use `async/await` features.

```
async function pull() {
    while (res.status == 'ONGOING')
        await dataFactory.pullFunction().then(function(res) {
            // my stuffs
        })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer @jkris but I don't want to use recursivity